# Binding to a list of classes populated by reading a json

Tags: c#, binding, viewmodel, maui

I am stuck again on this binding thing :-(

When creating a new ExpenseReport, I need to allow the user to select, among other things, an amount and a currency, for instance "37.4 GBP", so I need to show a numeric "ENTRY" field and a "CURRENCY" combobox.

---

I jave a Json named "Currencies.json" which looks like this:

```
{
  "AED": {
    "symbol": "AED",
    "name": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "symbol_native": "د.إ.‏",
    "decimal_digits": 2,
    "rounding": 0,
    "code": "AED",
    "name_plural": "UAE dirhams"
  },
  "AFN": {
    "symbol": "Af",
    "name": "Afghan Afghani",
    "symbol_native": "؋",
    "decimal_digits": 0,
    "rounding": 0,
    "code": "AFN",
    "name_plural": "Afghan Afghanis"
  },
```

..................
}

### Of course, I have this model:

```
public class Currency
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public int decimal_digits { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string name_plural { get; set; }
        public int rounding { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string symbol_native { get; set; }
    }
```

### I have an ExpenseReportNewExpense view and a ExpenseReportNewExpenseViewModel viewmodel, which looks like this:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(ExpenseReport), "ExpenseReport")]
public partial class ExpenseReportNewExpenseViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly CurrenciesService currenciesService;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ExpenseReport expenseReport;

    public ExpenseReportNewExpenseViewModel(CurrenciesService currenciesService)
    {
        this.currenciesService = currenciesService;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, Currency>> Currencies { get; } = new();
    public ObservableCollection<Currency> CurrenciesAsList { get; } = new();

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task GetCurrenciesAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            Dictionary<string, Currency> listOfCurrencies = await currenciesService.GetCurrencies();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Currency> keyValuePair in listOfCurrencies)
            {
                CurrenciesAsList.Add(keyValuePair.Value);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error!", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

and I have a CurrencyService which looks like this:

```
public class CurrenciesService
{
    private Dictionary<string, Currency> currenciesList;

    internal async Task<Dictionary<string, Currency>> GetCurrencies()
    {
        if (currenciesList?.Count > 0)
            return currenciesList;

        using Stream stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("Currencies.json");
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var contents = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        currenciesList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Currency>>(contents);

        return currenciesList;
    }

    internal async Task<Currency> GetCurrency(string Name)
    {
        if (currenciesList?.Count == 0)
        {
            using Stream stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("Currencies.json");
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var contents = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            currenciesList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Currency>>(contents);
        }

        var currency = currenciesList.Where(x => x.Value.name == Name).FirstOrDefault();
        return currency.Value;
    }
}
```

---

Because GetCurrencies() in my service returns a Dictionary<string, Currency>, and since I don't know how to use this for binding, I have created a new variable

```
public ObservableCollection<Currency> CurrenciesAsList { get; } = new();
```

and I'm populating it like so:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Currency> keyValuePair in listOfCurrencies)
    {
        CurrenciesAsList.Add(keyValuePair.Value);
    }
```

and I will bind to this variable instead.

(see above in the service)

---

I am  calling the method GetCurrenciesAsync() method in the codebehind of the view like so (I would like to call it, of course, only one time):

```
private readonly ExpenseReportNewExpenseViewModel viewModel;

    public ExpenseReportNewExpense(ExpenseReportNewExpenseViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        Title = $"#{viewModel.ExpenseReport.ID} [{AppRes.NewExpense}]";
        await this.viewModel.GetCurrenciesAsync();
    }
```

---

Okay. It all works - I am calling the GetCurrenciesAsync() method only once, and I obtain the currencies in the variable CurrenciesAsList of my viewmodel.

Thw problem appears to be in my view. I have this xaml:

---

```
<Label
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="1"
    HorizontalOptions="Start"
    TextColor="DarkSlateGray"
    Style="{StaticResource MediumLabelCentered}"
    Text="{x:Static res:AppRes.Amount}" />
<Picker
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="2"
    x:Name="picker"
    Title="Select a currency"
    ItemsSource ="{Binding CurrenciesAsList}"
    ItemDisplayBinding ="{Binding Currencies.Count}">
</Picker>
```

Question one:
I wanted at least to see the number 119 (which is the count of currencies in my json) in my picker. I don't.

Question two:
Of course, I actually wanted to see the names of my currencies, and not a count. I don't know how to do the binding to see that. I cannot write

```
<Picker
    Title="Select a currency"
    ItemsSource ="{Binding CurrenciesAsList}"
    ItemDisplayBinding ="{Binding symbol}">
</Picker>
```

because symbol is not exposed by my viewModel.

I have tried to  the viewModel so it exposes a Curreny object as well, but that doesn't work either. So... how do I bind to the "symbol" property of my Currency objects in my CurrenciesAsList List ?

Clearly, I am missing something - not only I cannot bind to the "symbol" property, I also cannot see at least the number of currencies in my currenciesList...

Thank you very much,
Alex

Comment: `Dictionary` is an `IEnumerable`, so you can just bind directly to it.  Try using "Value.name" as the `ItemDisplayBinding`

Comment: @Jason, with the above viewModel (cleansed by eliminating CurrenciesAsList), I can only bind to Currencies.Count:

<Picker
 Grid.Row="2"
 Grid.Column="2"
 x:Name="picker"
 Title="Select a currency"
 ItemsSource ="{Binding Currencies}"
 ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Currencies.Count}">
</Picker>

Comment: Alex with ItemDisplayBinding you told which property to display from each object. so you should do as jason said, ItemDisplayBinding ="{Binding PropertyFromListObject}"

Comment: @Alex also did you put [ObservableProperty]   on top of the CurrenciesAsList when you declare it? because as i see it's everything fine could be that!

Comment: @LeandroToloza Yes, but ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding symbol}"> says "Member not found in DataContext " (See my viewmodel above)... And ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Currencies.Value.symbol}"> doesn't work either. It only compiles with  ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Currencies.Count}", but even then it doesn't show anything.. I am clearly doing something stupid here ! :-((

Comment: @Alex i think you should put [ObservableProperty] ont top of each declaration of the observable Collections

Comment: `ItemDisplayBinding ="{Binding Value.symbol}">`